# qTempfile module python - file doesn't exists in return statement

Tags: python, http, web, temporary-files

The following code creates a tempdir and a named temp file with `tempfile` module.
Everything works as expected and the the midi file seem to exists when printing `os.path.exists(..midipath..)`

When returning `FileResponse`, the code goes to `except` block and fails with error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpapxfo5e_/tmpmgwacvxf_basic_pitch.mid'
```

I'm new to Python and not sure how things work internally but from reading about `tempfile` i understood that the file lives inside the `with` scope, where the return statement is.

Thank for the help!

```
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir_path:
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wb') as tmpfile:
                tmpfile.write(binary)

                predict_and_save(
                    [os.path.join(tmpdir_path, tmpfile.name)],             
                    output_directory=tmpdir_path,
                    save_midi=True,
                    sonify_midi=False,
                    save_model_outputs=False,
                    save_notes=False
                )

                midi_soffix = '_basic_pitch.mid'
                midi_filepath = f'{tmpdir_path}/{os.path.basename(tmpfile.name)}{midi_soffix}'
                print(os.path.exists(midi_filepath))
                return FileResponse(midi_filepath, media_type='audio/midi',filename=file.filename + '_basic_pitch.mid')
```

### Edit

I now see that the return statement does return 200 to my client (the FileResponse class is from FastAPI) but the error comes after.
So the I guess when the file streams to the client it's already not existing.

I guess it becomes a fastapi issues rather tempfile.
Would anyone have an idea about that?

Comment: Could you please explain what you think your code is doing / supposed to do?  Also, please include the full traceback of the error message.

Comment: This would depend on the internal details of the `FileResponse` class (which I know nothing about - there are at least two popular packages with such a class).  If it entirely consumed the file during instantiation, that would work just fine.  If it just saved the filename in an instance attribute, and only actually read the file during some method call that will be performed later, it would fail because the `with` block has been exited before that method call gets made.

Comment: Without more details, I would guess that the problem either as to do with a) you're mixing an unrelated temporary directory and temporary file in `os.path.join(tmpdir_path, tmpfile.name)`, or b) `FileResponse` doesn't attempt to read the file contents until it needs to later on, after the file has already been unlinked.

Comment: the FileResponse class belong to FastApi.
Essentially what im trying to do is create a midi file on my server and send it back to the client.
I'm creating a temp dir and strong 2 files - original audio file and newly created midi file. After it is sent to the client i want it to be removed.

Comment: Edited the question. Comments here shad some light on the internal process. Seems like fastapi does return 200 and only after send the file.

Still not sure how i can send a file and delete it right after. Wouldnt want to implemented cron jobs now.

Comment: After `return` the `tmpfile` or path to it is removed, so it doesn't exist afterwards.